# Project tablet to TV and run video when tablet is in stand by

Tags: remote, tv, tablet-pc

What i'm trying to achieve is this:

1. I'm gonna run an app to a tablet(iOS or Android) which will be connected to a TV, and I want to be able to see what I'm doing on tablet to that TV(project screen)
2. In the same time, when I'm not playing with the app, on TV should run some movies(like a screen saver on Windows)

I'm wondering how and if this kind of thing can be done

Comment: An Android or iOS tablet is not a tablet-PC.  Smartphones and their tablet-like cousins are off topic here. Android questions belong on [android.se] while iOS  questions belong on [Apple.se]. This does not involve computer hardware within the scope of our site.

Comment: ok @Mokubai, I thought that it will be easier to post it here then to other 2 different sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Android set-top box with ChromeCast should be able to do this along with an Android tablet that supports casting. An appropriate Daydream mode or app on the set-top box should run whenever not casting.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! If I just want to project tablet screen only what choices do I have(wired or wireless)?

Comment: Chromecast will use whatever network connection you have available.